# How Does $ {L}_{1} $ Regularization Present Itself in Gradient Descent?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, vector-analysis, gradient-descent, regularization

If we incorporated $ {L}_{1} $ Loss in gradient descent, how would the update rule change? It's easy to write down the optimization objective. But I'm not sure what to put for the update rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the gradient of the norm does not exist at $0$, so you need to be careful

$$
E_{L_1} = E + \lambda\sum_{k=1}^N|\beta_k|
$$

where $E$ is the cost function (E stands for error), which I will assume you already know how to calculate the gradient for.

As for the regularization term, note that if $\beta_k > 0$ then $|\beta_k| = \beta_k$ and the gradient is $+1$, similarly when $\beta_k < 0$ the gradient is $-1$, so in summary

$$
\frac{\partial |\beta_k|}{\partial \beta_l} = {\rm sgn}(\beta_k)\delta_{kl}
$$

so that

$$
\frac{\partial E_{L_1}}{\partial \beta_l} = \frac{\partial E}{\partial \beta_l} + \lambda\sum_{k=1}^N {\rm sgn}(\beta_k)\delta_{kl} = \frac{\partial E}{\partial \beta_l} + \lambda {\rm sgn}(\beta_l)
$$

Answer (score 4):

It changes the direction you descent towards.

You may have a look at this PDF - [Steepest Descent Direction for Various Norms](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://github.com/RoyiAvital/Projects/raw/master/Optimization/SteepestDescent/SteepestDescentNorms.pdf).
It shows the direction for few different norms.

Comment: Thanks for the PDF, did you write that? It's pretty good.

Comment: Yes. Yet I'm not sure when I read you question again that this is what you meant.